# limiting the number of decimal places in python pandas table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to rewrite a CSV file using pandas module in python. I tried to multiply the first column (excluding the title) by 60 as below,

```
 f=001.csv
 Urbs_Data=pd.read_csv(f,header=None)
 Urbs_Data=Urbs_Data.replace("Time_hrs","Time_min")
 Urbs_Data.loc[1:,0]=Urbs_Data.loc[1:,0].astype(float)
 Urbs_Data.loc[1:,0]*=60
```

It gives me some funny number for the first column, as

> 124.98000000000002,462.67
>
> 130.01999999999998,460.34
>
> 135.0,454.36
>
> 139.98000000000002,443.29

Is there any way to limit the number of decimal places for those numbers (to 2)? I tried to use the normal round function, it does not work for me.

Comment: show me how do you use round function

Comment: I did as  Urbs_Data.loc[1:,0].astype(float)=round(Urbs_Data.loc[1:,0].astype(float),2)

Comment: you got the answer

Answer (score 35):

The DataFrame [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) method should work...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

some_numbers = np.random.ranf(5)

df = pd.DataFrame({'random_numbers':some_numbers})

rounded_df = df.round(decimals=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

#fileName
f=001.csv

#Load File to Df
Urbs_Data=pd.read_csv(f,header=None)

#Round of all the numeric values to the specified decimal value
Urbs_Data= Urbs_Data.round(decimals=3)
```

This rounding off will be applied on all the Numeric columns